# RKManagedObjectMapping in RestKit 0.2?

Tags: restkit

What happened to `RKManagedObjectMapping` in RestKit 0.2? Where can I find documentation on the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the examples provided [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) to understand how to change your code to the new architecture.